# Python: Find list elements with part of it as a duplicate. A logic to work would be sufficient

Tags: python, list

```
List1 = ['ABCD_123.A_062320_082824', 'ABCD_123.A_062320_094024','ABCD_123.A_063020_084447']
```

I want to keep the last element as it has the latest time stamp `MonDayYear_HrMinSec`

```
Method 1

names = []
for name in list1:
         names.append(name.split('_')[0])
         Day = name.split('_')[-2]
         Time = name.split('_')[-1]
     
     print(names,Day,Time)

Method 2 
     for name in list1: 
         namematch = re.search(r'^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(__[\d]*.A_)([\d]{6})_([\d]{6})',name)
         names.append(namematch.group(1))
         
     #print(names)
```

I tried regex which works but I dont know how to check for corresponding group. DO I use an if condition checking for group 2 and 3 and keep group1 or something along those lines?

Comment: Is the name structure always `name_date_time`?

Comment: And, your code doesn't actually check if the prefix is the same.  Will there be items with different prefixes?  And you're not actually keeping all the timestamps.  Maybe post what your desired output is, with a more complicated input example?

Comment: @ Ehsan Yes. Structure is always name_date_time

Comment: @Ram Then the posted answer should help you. Thank you.

Comment: @user120242 Yes I was going to do that. Check if prefix is the same then find the corresponding date and time and keep the list element with latest time stamp. But did not know the logic to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this (assuming structure is `name_date_time`):

```
from itertools import groupby
out = [sorted(list(v))[-1] for k,v in groupby(sorted(List1), key=lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[:-2]))]
```

**Explanation**:

- Split your elements by `'_'` and throw away date and time and join the rest by `'_'` to form the names
- Use groupby to group by names and then sort each group
- Select the last in the sorted group (if you sort, latest date and time will come last)

output (Note that the order of elements can be different in this solution. If you need to keep the order, simply keep the order of names and reorder this by that):

```
['ABCD_123.A_063020_084447']
```

Another example:

```
List1 = ['ABCE_123.A_062320_082824', 'ABCE_123.A_062320_094024','ABCD_123.A_063020_084447']
```

out:

```
['ABCD_123.A_063020_084447', 'ABCE_123.A_062320_094024']
```